# login to Azure from a script

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I want to run shell script on Linux using azure-cli (az command) that login to Azure without entering password and run other azure-cli commands without login again.

First, I once run '*az login*', it create a .azure under my home directory, who save all the login information and give me ability to run other az command without login again. 
After few weeks/months it stop working, running '*az login*' again solved the problem.

1. Is there any way that I can cancel/increase the expiration date saved in .azure directory, so I will not need to run '*az login*' again?
2. I consider adding app user. I follow the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal) to create application user. In 'New application registration' it ask "Sign-on URL" what is the value I need to enter, I have no url for my script.

What it the best way to keep login to azure from a script without entering password?

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recommended way to do unattended logins from scripts is by using a service principal with a certificate.

See e.g. [Create an Azure service principal with Azure CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-resource-manager%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-cli-latest) for instructions on how to set up the certificate and service principal and how to do the actual login.

The above link has instructions for settings this up for AzureRM PowerShell as well as for Azure CLI.

Comment: You can create a self signed certificate using the New-SelfSignedCertificate command. See e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal?view=azure-cli-latest#create-service-principal-with-self-signed-certificate code example on how its syntax looks like

Comment: if I want to use --cert, how can I generate a cert string?  also I try to connect and got the error:Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response: {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"AADSTS70001: Application with identifier 'username' was not found in the directory...."error_codes":[70001],...

Comment: I had mistake in the parameters I write in the command. I fixed it and it worked